# Stepping Thread Group vs Number of Samples JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmx, threadgroup

I want to understand the relation between Stepping up Thread Groups and Number of Samples.

[Stepping Thread Group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Lfla.png)

My Test Plan looks like this:

[Test Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faC8f.png)

But in the Summary report I am getting #Samples more than 10 for certain Requests. Not able to understand how is it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual number of [Sample Results](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) will not necessarily be 10 as:

1. JMeter starts 1 thread each 2 second until the number of threads will be 10
2. Once started thread starts executing Samplers upside down
3. When thread finishes executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) and 60 seconds of duration has not yet passed the threads **starts over**

So the actual number of Samplers which will be executed in 60 seconds by 10 threads will depend mostly on your **application response time**.

Check out [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/) article to learn more about correlation of number of virtual users and delivered load